# Can implicit differentiation ever give misleading answers? (for calculus students who don't know the implicit function theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at a point $P = (x_0,y_0)$ where $f(P) = 0$. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P) \ne 0$, then we may use implicit differentiation to find the slopes of tangent lines to the graph of
$$f(x,y) = 0$$
at $P$.

What happens if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P) = 0$?

In this case, it is still possible for implicit differentiation to yield a sensible result. For example, you can take $f(x,y) = y^2$ and $P = (0,0)$, then implicit differentiation yields $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$, but in this case it makes sense - after all the graph of $y^2 = 0$ is just a horizontal line.

My question is - could implicit differentiation yield a finite well defined result that doesn't make sense?

To make this slightly more precise, suppose that near $P$ (a point with $f(P) = 0$), $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is not identically 0. Thus near $P$, implicit differentiation will yield values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Suppose $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P) = 0$, then is it possible for the limit of these $\frac{dy}{dx}$'s obtained by implicit differentiation to exist at $P$ and yet for it to be nonsensical? (Ie, for it to not equal the slope of some tangent line to $f(x,y) = 0$ at $P$?)

Basically, I'm wondering how bad it is to tell calculus students (who don't know about partial derivatives) that "you can always use implicit differentation as long as everything is differentiable".

Comment: Consider $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ at the point $(1, 0)$. The tangent line is vertical.

Comment: @AJY What is your point?

Comment: At that point, you’ll have $\partial f / \partial y (P) = 0$. The limits of $dy/dx$ won’t exist, which makes sense since the line would have undefined slope.

Comment: @AJY I agree. My question is - must the limit always fail to exist when $\partial f/\partial y = 0$? Ie, could one find some differentiable $f$ with $(\partial f/\partial y)(P) = 0$ but the limit of the $dy/dx$'s exists? Such an example would yield a misleading answer since one could presumably use implicit differentiation to derive a formula for $dy/dx$ which makes sense at $P$ despite the implicit function theorem failing to hold.

Comment: You’ll have that near $P$, where $\partial f / \partial y \neq 0$, you get $dy/dx = (\partial f / \partial x) / (\partial f / \partial y)$. For this to converge will force that $\partial f / \partial x \to 0$, so $\partial f / \partial x (P) = 0$.

Comment: There’s also the problem that $dy/dx$ is meaningless unless $y$ is a function of $x$, which in my circle example is not the case.